# Can I use react router in django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, react-router

I have a project that uses React in frontend and Django as backend.

Also I use react router in my project and the code looks like this:

```xml
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/teachers" exact component={Teachers} />
        <Route path="/courses" exact component={Courses}/>
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/posts" exact component={Posts} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In django my urls file looks like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

The problem is that whenever I try to navigate to the page from react router I get 404 error from django.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dude I am having the same problem.  From I have researched the answer is actually to throw a catch all at the end of your urls in django.  I can only find the old way of doing it.

```
url(r'^(%s)?$' % '|'.join(routes), TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

I am not sure how to do it with path but I had found it earlier. It might be

```
re_path(r'.*', views.index)
```

Just let me know if that works so I can go home and use it :)

Comment: I have used ```re_path``` and it worked pretty well! Thanks a lot dawg!

Comment: Nice, I just got my first answer ever!  Thank you sir!